# Extremely slow network and half duplex

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, nic, ethtool

I am having an extremely slow network

netperf -H 11.x.x.21

```
TCP STREAM TEST from 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0) port 0 AF_INET to 11.x.x.21 (11.x.x.19) port 0 AF_INET

Recv   Send    Send  Socket Socket  Message  Elapsed              
Size   Size    Size     Time     Throughput  
bytes  bytes   bytes    secs.    10^6bits/sec  

2288  16384  16384    10.16       0.41
```

I dont understand why 11.x.x.21 is showing

**ethtool eth0**

```
Settings for eth0:
Supported ports: [ FIBRE ]
Supported link modes:   1000baseT/Full 
Supported pause frame use: No
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 1000Mb/s
```

> **Duplex: Half**

```
Port: FIBRE
PHYAD: 2
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
Supports Wake-on: g
Wake-on: g
Link detected: yes
```

tried **ethtool -r eth0** but no change at all.

so Manually changed by

> **ethtool -s eth0 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg off**

But still no change in netperf ouptput

**ethtool -i eth0**

```
driver: bnx2
version: 2.1.11
firmware-version: bc 5.0.6 NCSI 2.0.3
bus-info: 0000:10:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
```

**lspci**

```
00:10.0 PIC: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500/X58 Physical and Link Layer Registers Port 0 (rev 13)
```

Any idea:

why auto negotiation put NIC to half duplex and

Why manually changing to Full duplex couldnt solve anything.

Comment: If you manually configure duplex and speed settings, then this should also be configured on the individual switch port.

Comment: Have you checked if on the switch side the negotiation is also set to auto and not half duplex? Also might be due to a broken cable.

Comment: @Chris i forgot to mention that after reboot it came up wit this 
[   28.088830] bnx2 0000:10:00.0: eth0: NIC SerDes Link is Up, 1000 Mbps full duplex

Comment: So it means your problem is solved or is it still slow?

Comment: If i restart its detecting proper duplex mode,not able to do i with ethtool

Answer (score 1):

First check that the setting on the device you connect to, do match (1000, autoneg, full-duplex).

Second swap the cable.

Third swap the port you are connecting to.